# I2C issue communicating with an analog to digital converter mux ADS1015 through TCA9548A I2C multiplexor

Tags: raspberry-pi, i2c, embedded, serial, communication

I am using a Raspberry Pi Zero 2 to talk through a TCA9548A to multiple ADS1015, each ADS1015 is on a separate SDA/SCL channel of the TCA9548A. I am able to scan all channels and see the active addresses (0x48) on channel 0 of the TCA9548A and channel 1 of the TCA9548A.

I am not sure how to write the Python code to select the analog input 0 on the channel 0 ADS1015 and then read the conversion,  then change to channel 1 of the TCA9548A and select/read analog input 2 of the ADS1015 on that channel.

When I run the example code that scans channels on the TCA9548A I can see the 2 ADS1015s on channel 0 and channel 1.

[image]

I must not be setting up the ADS object correctly to talk to the ads1015 chip through the TCA9548A because all I get is a blank screen after channel 1 is locked and then the program stalls.

[image]

I am new to Python and the Adafruit code examples are just not clicking with me. Could someone explain in layman's terms how the code makes requests to the chips and how the addressing works?

Comment: Are you sure it's a software issue? Is there a manual for those functions? Also, isn't this a dupe of your previous question?

Comment: @justme thanks for the insight